# Foundation email template - Gmail does not display any template style

Tags: zurb-foundation, html-email, codeigniter-3

I am sending an email with Codeigniter 3 configurations'm doing for the mailings in HTML format, here the configuration code.

**Mail settings:**

```
$config = Array (
    'priority'  => 1,
    'protocol'  => 'mail', 
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'email@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'utf-8', // iso-8859-1
    'wordwrap'  => TRUE, 
    'newline'   => "\r\n"
);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function email() 
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('email@email.com', 'Names');
    $this->email->to('email@email.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');

    $data['nombre'] = 'Example';
    $body = $this->load->view('email/test.php',$data,TRUE);
    //$this->email->attach("/assets/images/logo.png", "inline");
    $this->email->message($body);
    if ($this->email->send()) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
    $this->email->clear(TRUE);
}
```

**View - Default email template Foundation:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<style>
#outlook a {
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    width: 100%!important;
    min-width: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
    line-height: 100%;
}
#backgroundTable {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%!important;
    line-height: 100%!important;
}
img {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
center {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 580px;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    word-break: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse!important;
}
table, tr, td {
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}
hr {
    color: #d9d9d9;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
}
table.body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
table.container {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: inherit;
}
table.row {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
table.container table.row {
    display: block;
}
td.wrapper {
    padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
}
table.columns, table.column {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table.columns td, table.column td {
    padding: 0px 0px 10px;
}
table.columns td.sub-columns, table.column td.sub-columns, table.columns td.sub-column, table.column td.sub-column {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
td.sub-column, td.sub-columns {
    min-width: 0px;
}
table.row td.last, table.container td.last {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
table.one {
    width: 30px;
}
table.two {
    width: 80px;
}
table.three {
    width: 130px;
}
table.four {
    width: 180px;
}
table.five {
    width: 230px;
}
table.six {
    width: 280px;
}
table.seven {
    width: 330px;
}
table.eight {
    width: 380px;
}
table.nine {
    width: 430px;
}
table.ten {
    width: 480px;
}
table.eleven {
    width: 530px;
}
table.twelve {
    width: 580px;
}
table.one center {
    min-width: 30px;
}
table.two center {
    min-width: 80px;
}
table.three center {
    min-width: 130px;
}
table.four center {
    min-width: 180px;
}
table.five center {
    min-width: 230px;
}
table.six center {
    min-width: 280px;
}
table.seven center {
    min-width: 330px;
}
table.eight center {
    min-width: 380px;
}
table.nine center {
    min-width: 430px;
}
table.ten center {
    min-width: 480px;
}
table.eleven center {
    min-width: 530px;
}
table.twelve center {
    min-width: 580px;
}
table.one .panel center {
    min-width: 10px;
}
table.two .panel center {
    min-width: 60px;
}
table.three .panel center {
    min-width: 110px;
}
table.four .panel center {
    min-width: 160px;
}
table.five .panel center {
    min-width: 210px;
}
table.six .panel center {
    min-width: 260px;
}
table.seven .panel center {
    min-width: 310px;
}
table.eight .panel center {
    min-width: 360px;
}
table.nine .panel center {
    min-width: 410px;
}
table.ten .panel center {
    min-width: 460px;
}
table.eleven .panel center {
    min-width: 510px;
}
table.twelve .panel center {
    min-width: 560px;
}
.body .columns td.one, .body .column td.one {
    width: 8.333333%;
}
.body .columns td.two, .body .column td.two {
    width: 16.666666%;
}
.body .columns td.three, .body .column td.three {
    width: 25%;
}
.body .columns td.four, .body .column td.four {
    width: 33.333333%;
}
.body .columns td.five, .body .column td.five {
    width: 41.666666%;
}
.body .columns td.six, .body .column td.six {
    width: 50%;
}
.body .columns td.seven, .body .column td.seven {
    width: 58.333333%;
}
.body .columns td.eight, .body .column td.eight {
    width: 66.666666%;
}
.body .columns td.nine, .body .column td.nine {
    width: 75%;
}
.body .columns td.ten, .body .column td.ten {
    width: 83.333333%;
}
.body .columns td.eleven, .body .column td.eleven {
    width: 91.666666%;
}
.body .columns td.twelve, .body .column td.twelve {
    width: 100%;
}
td.offset-by-one {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
td.offset-by-two {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
td.offset-by-three {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
td.offset-by-four {
    padding-left: 200px;
}
td.offset-by-five {
    padding-left: 250px;
}
td.offset-by-six {
    padding-left: 300px;
}
td.offset-by-seven {
    padding-left: 350px;
}
td.offset-by-eight {
    padding-left: 400px;
}
td.offset-by-nine {
    padding-left: 450px;
}
td.offset-by-ten {
    padding-left: 500px;
}
td.offset-by-eleven {
    padding-left: 550px;
}
td.expander {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0px;
    padding: 0!important;
}
table.columns .text-pad, table.column .text-pad {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
table.columns .left-text-pad, table.columns .text-pad-left, table.column .left-text-pad, table.column .text-pad-left {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
table.columns .right-text-pad, table.columns .text-pad-right, table.column .right-text-pad, table.column .text-pad-right {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.block-grid {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 580px;
}
.block-grid td {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.two-up td {
    width: 270px;
}
.three-up td {
    width: 173px;
}
.four-up td {
    width: 125px;
}
.five-up td {
    width: 96px;
}
.six-up td {
    width: 76px;
}
.seven-up td {
    width: 62px;
}
.eight-up td {
    width: 52px;
}
table.center, td.center {
    text-align: center;
}
h1.center, h2.center, h3.center, h4.center, h5.center, h6.center {
    text-align: center;
}
span.center {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
img.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
.show-for-small, .hide-for-desktop {
    display: none;
}
body, table.body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, td {
    color: #222222;
    font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    word-break: normal;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 32px;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 28px;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
body, table.body, p, td {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 19px;
}
p.lead, p.lede, p.leed {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
small {
    font-size: 10px;
}
a {
    color: #2ba6cb;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #2795b6!important;
}
a:active {
    color: #2795b6!important;
}
a:visited {
    color: #2ba6cb!important;
}
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
    color: #2ba6cb;
}
h1 a:active, h2 a:active, h3 a:active, h4 a:active, h5 a:active, h6 a:active {
    color: #2ba6cb!important;
}
h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited, h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited {
    color: #2ba6cb!important;
}
.panel {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    padding: 10px!important;
}
.sub-grid table {
    width: 100%;
}
.sub-grid td.sub-columns {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
table.button, table.tiny-button, table.small-button, table.medium-button, table.large-button {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
table.button td, table.tiny-button td, table.small-button td, table.medium-button td, table.large-button td {
    display: block;
    width: auto!important;
    text-align: center;
    background: #2ba6cb;
    border: 1px solid #2284a1;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px 0;
}
table.tiny-button td {
    padding: 5px 0 4px;
}
table.small-button td {
    padding: 8px 0 7px;
}
table.medium-button td {
    padding: 12px 0 10px;
}
table.large-button td {
    padding: 21px 0 18px;
}
table.button td a, table.tiny-button td a, table.small-button td a, table.medium-button td a, table.large-button td a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
table.tiny-button td a {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
table.small-button td a {
    font-size: 16px;
}
table.medium-button td a {
    font-size: 20px;
}
table.large-button td a {
    font-size: 24px;
}
table.button:hover td, table.button:visited td, table.button:active td {
    background: #2795b6!important;
}
table.button:hover td a, table.button:visited td a, table.button:active td a {
    color: #fff!important;
}
table.button:hover td, table.tiny-button:hover td, table.small-button:hover td, table.medium-button:hover td, table.large-button:hover td {
    background: #2795b6!important;
}
table.button:hover td a, table.button:active td a, table.button td a:visited, table.tiny-button:hover td a, table.tiny-button:active td a, table.tiny-button td a:visited, table.small-button:hover td a, table.small-button:active td a, table.small-button td a:visited, table.medium-button:hover td a, table.medium-button:active td a, table.medium-button td a:visited, table.large-button:hover td a, table.large-button:active td a, table.large-button td a:visited {
    color: #ffffff!important;
}
table.secondary td {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    border-color: #d0d0d0;
    color: #555;
}
table.secondary td a {
    color: #555;
}
table.secondary:hover td {
    background: #d0d0d0!important;
    color: #555;
}
table.secondary:hover td a, table.secondary td a:visited, table.secondary:active td a {
    color: #555!important;
}
table.success td {
    background: #5da423;
    border-color: #457a1a;
}
table.success:hover td {
    background: #457a1a!important;
}
table.alert td {
    background: #c60f13;
    border-color: #970b0e;
}
table.alert:hover td {
    background: #970b0e!important;
}
table.radius td {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
table.round td {
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
    border-radius: 500px;
}
body.outlook p {
    display: inline!important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
table[class="body"] img {
    width: auto!important;
    height: auto!important;
}
table[class="body"] center {
    min-width: 0!important;
}
table[class="body"] .container {
    width: 95%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .row {
    width: 100%!important;
    display: block!important;
}
table[class="body"] .wrapper {
    display: block!important;
    padding-right: 0!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns, table[class="body"] .column {
    table-layout: fixed!important;
    float: none!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    padding-right: 0px!important;
    padding-left: 0px!important;
    display: block!important;
}
table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .columns, table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .column {
    display: table!important;
}
table[class="body"] table.columns td, table[class="body"] table.column td {
    width: 100%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.one, table[class="body"] .column td.one {
    width: 8.333333%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.two, table[class="body"] .column td.two {
    width: 16.666666%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.three, table[class="body"] .column td.three {
    width: 25%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.four, table[class="body"] .column td.four {
    width: 33.333333%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.five, table[class="body"] .column td.five {
    width: 41.666666%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.six, table[class="body"] .column td.six {
    width: 50%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.seven, table[class="body"] .column td.seven {
    width: 58.333333%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.eight, table[class="body"] .column td.eight {
    width: 66.666666%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.nine, table[class="body"] .column td.nine {
    width: 75%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.ten, table[class="body"] .column td.ten {
    width: 83.333333%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.eleven, table[class="body"] .column td.eleven {
    width: 91.666666%!important;
}
table[class="body"] .columns td.twelve, table[class="body"] .column td.twelve {
    width: 100%!important;
}
table[class="body"] td.offset-by-one, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-two, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-three, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-four, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-five, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-six, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-seven, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eight, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-nine, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-ten, table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eleven {
    padding-left: 0!important;
}
table[class="body"] table.columns td.expander {
    width: 1px!important;
}
table[class="body"] .right-text-pad, table[class="body"] .text-pad-right {
    padding-left: 10px!important;
}
table[class="body"] .left-text-pad, table[class="body"] .text-pad-left {
    padding-right: 10px!important;
}
table[class="body"] .hide-for-small, table[class="body"] .show-for-desktop {
    display: none!important;
}
table[class="body"] .show-for-small, table[class="body"] .hide-for-desktop {
    display: inherit!important;
}
}
</style>
<style>
table.facebook td{background:#3b5998;border-color:#2d4473;}table.facebook:hover td{background:#2d4473!important;}table.twitter td{background:#00acee;border-color:#0087bb;}table.twitter:hover td{background:#0087bb!important;}table.google-plus td{background-color:#DB4A39;border-color:#CC0000;}table.google-plus:hover td{background:#CC0000!important;}.template-label{color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;}.callout .panel{background:#ECF8FF;border-color:#b9e5ff;}.header{background:#999999;}.footer .wrapper{background:#ebebeb;}.footer h5{padding-bottom:10px;}table.columns .text-pad{padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;}table.columns .left-text-pad{padding-left:10px;}table.columns .right-text-pad{padding-right:10px;}@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {table[class="body"] .right-text-pad{padding-left:10px!important;}table[class="body"] .left-text-pad{padding-right:10px!important;}}
</style>
<style>
table.facebook td{background:#3b5998;border-color:#2d4473;}table.facebook:hover td{background:#2d4473!important;}table.twitter td{background:#00acee;border-color:#0087bb;}table.twitter:hover td{background:#0087bb!important;}table.google-plus td{background-color:#DB4A39;border-color:#CC0000;}table.google-plus:hover td{background:#CC0000!important;}.template-label{color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;}.callout .panel{background:#ECF8FF;border-color:#b9e5ff;}.header{background:#999999;}.footer .wrapper{background:#ebebeb;}.footer h5{padding-bottom:10px;}table.columns .text-pad{padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;}table.columns .left-text-pad{padding-left:10px;}table.columns .right-text-pad{padding-right:10px;}@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {table[class="body"] .right-text-pad{padding-left:10px!important;}table[class="body"] .left-text-pad{padding-right:10px!important;}}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">ANCHORFREE_VERSION="413161526"</script><script type='text/javascript'>(function(){if(typeof(_AF2$runned)!='undefined'&&_AF2$runned==true){return}_AF2$={'SN':'HSSHIELD00ZZ','IP':'85.237.197.240','CH':'HSSCNL100680','CT':'oxm,z234','HST':'&isUpdated=0','AFH':'hss439','RN':Math.floor(Math.random()*999),'TOP':(parent.location!=document.location||top.location!=document.location)?0:1,'AFVER':'5.2.1','FBW':'','FBWCNT':0};if(/^(.*,)?(11C)(,.*)?$/g.exec(_AF2$.CT)!=null){document.write("<scr"+"ipt src='http://box.anchorfree.net/insert/par.js?v="+ANCHORFREE_VERSION+"' type='text/javascript'></scr"+"ipt>")}document.write("<style type='text/css' title='AFc_css"+_AF2$.RN+"' >.AFc_body"+_AF2$.RN+"{} .AFc_all"+_AF2$.RN+",a.AFc_all"+_AF2$.RN+":hover,a.AFc_all"+_AF2$.RN+":visited{outline:none;background:transparent;border:none;margin:0;padding:0;top:0;left:0;text-decoration:none;overflow:hidden;display:block;z-index:666999;}</style>");})();</script>
<style type='text/css'>
.AFhss_dpnone{display:none;width:0;height:0}
</style>
<img src="about:blank"id="AFhss_trk"name="AFhss_trk"style="display:none"/>
<div id="AFhss_dfs"class="AFhss_dpnone">
  <div id="AFhss_adrp0"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
  <div id="AFhss_adrp1"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
  <div id="AFhss_adrp2"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
  <div id="AFhss_adrp3"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
  <div id="AFhss_adrp4"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
  <div id="AFhss_adrp5"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
  <div id="AFhss_adrp6"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
  <div id="AFhss_adrp7"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
  <div id="AFhss_adrp8"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
  <div id="AFhss_adrp9"class="AFhss_dpnone"></div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>(function(){if(typeof(_AF2$runned)!='undefined'&&_AF2$runned==true){return}_AF2$={'SN':'HSSHIELD00ZZ','IP':'85.237.197.240','CH':'HSSCNL100680','CT':'oxm,z234','HST':'&isUpdated=0','AFH':'hss439','RN':Math.floor(Math.random()*999),'TOP':(parent.location!=document.location||top.location!=document.location)?0:1,'AFVER':'5.2.1','FBW':'','FBWCNT':0};if(_AF2$.TOP==1){document.write("<scr"+"ipt src='http://box.anchorfree.net/insert/41.js?v="+ANCHORFREE_VERSION+"' type='text/javascript'></scr"+"ipt>")}})()</script>
<table class="body">
  <tr>
    <td class="center" align="center" valign="top"><center>
        <table class="row header">
          <tr>
            <td class="center" align="center"><center>
                <table class="container">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="wrapper last"><table class="twelve columns">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="six sub-columns"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x50"></td>
                          <td class="six sub-columns last" align="right" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;"><span class="template-label">HERO</span></td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </center></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <td><table class="row">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper last"><table class="twelve columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td><h1>Hi, Elijah Baily</h1>
                          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.</p>
                          <img width="580" height="300" src="http://placehold.it/580x300"></td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="row callout">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper last"><table class="twelve columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="panel"><p>Phasellus dictum sapien a neque luctus cursus. Pellentesque sem dolor, fringilla et pharetra vitae. <a href="#">Click it! »</a></p></td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="row">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper last"><table class="twelve columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td><h3>Title Ipsum <small>This is a note.</small></h3>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="row">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper last"><table class="three columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td><table class="button">
                            <tr>
                              <td><a href="#">Click Me!</a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="row footer">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper"><table class="six columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="left-text-pad"><h5>Connect With Us:</h5>
                          <table class="tiny-button facebook">
                            <tr>
                              <td><a href="#">Facebook</a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <br>
                          <table class="tiny-button twitter">
                            <tr>
                              <td><a href="#">Twitter</a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <br>
                          <table class="tiny-button google-plus">
                            <tr>
                              <td><a href="#">Google +</a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                  <td class="wrapper last"><table class="six columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="last right-text-pad"><h5>Contact Info:</h5>
                          <p>Phone: 408.341.0600</p>
                          <p>Email: <a href="mailto:hseldon@trantor.com">hseldon@trantor.com</a></p></td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="row">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper last"><table class="twelve columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center"><center>
                            <p style="text-align:center;"><a href="#">Terms</a> | <a href="#">Privacy</a> | <a href="#">Unsubscribe</a></p>
                          </center></td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**The mail is displayed without style:**

[image]

*Would greatly appreciate your support, thank you very much.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and reading many forums, I found the solution thanks to the community email Foundation among others, I explain here the details for those who can be useful.

Most companies like emails, Gmail, AOL, Hotmail etc ... They clean the tags `<style>` that they are located within the `<head>`, this is done to avoid conflicts of CSS, so the solution is to place all inline styles within each label correspodan, example:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500;">My title</h1>
```

Do this for a line is very easy, but when we want a sleek, well crafted template with a very high level of detail, it would be counterintuitive to do this once, for this there is a conversion technique called Emogrifier, which greatly facilitates work, which debmos do is design and layout our base template, with organized and separated styles, to have a well structured and organized page, but same not can send by email, so I mentioned, we have to Emogrifier the sketch prepared by pasting all the HTML and CSS code, and for this there are many tools, here I leave 3 highly recommended, but there are many.

**Recommended pages:**

1. http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html
2. http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/
3. https://www.myintervals.com/emogrifier.php

**The email template that you perform should look like this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Avenir Next', "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.65;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
body, .body-wrap {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    background: #efefef;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
a {
    color: #71bc37;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.text-right {
    text-align: right;
}
.text-left {
    text-align: left;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background: #71bc37;
    border: solid #71bc37;
    border-width: 10px 20px 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
}
p, ul, ol {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.container {
    display: block !important;
    clear: both !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 580px !important;
}
.container table {
    width: 100% !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.container .masthead {
    padding: 80px 0;
    background: #71bc37;
    color: white;
}
.container .masthead h1 {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 90%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.container .content {
    background: white;
    padding: 30px 35px;
}
.container .content.footer {
    background: none;
}
.container .content.footer p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #888;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.container .content.footer a {
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="body-wrap">
  <tr>
    <td class="container"><!-- Message start -->

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" class="masthead"><h1>Something Big...</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="content"><h2>Hi Stranger,</h2>
            <p>Kielbasa venison ball tip shankle. Boudin prosciutto landjaeger, pancetta jowl turkey tri-tip porchetta beef pork loin drumstick. Frankfurter short ribs kevin pig ribeye drumstick bacon kielbasa. Pork loin brisket biltong, pork belly filet mignon ribeye pig ground round porchetta turducken turkey. Pork belly beef ribs sausage ham hock, ham doner frankfurter pork chop tail meatball beef pig meatloaf short ribs shoulder. Filet mignon ham hock kielbasa beef ribs shank. Venison swine beef ribs sausage pastrami shoulder.</p>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><p> <a href="#" class="button">Share the Awesomeness</a> </p></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <p>By the way, if you're wondering where you can find more of this fine meaty filler, visit <a href="http://baconipsum.com">Bacon Ipsum</a>.</p>
            <p><em>– Mr. Pen</em></p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="container"><!-- Message start -->

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="content footer" align="center"><p>Sent by <a href="#">Company Name</a>, 1234 Yellow Brick Road, OZ, 99999</p>
            <p><a href="mailto:">hello@company.com</a> | <a href="#">Unsubscribe</a></p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**When processing or make the Emogrifier, you should be as follows:**

```
<!-- Inliner Build Version 4380b7741bb759d6cb997545f3add21ad48f010b -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  </head>
  <body style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; width: 100% !important; height: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background: #efefef; margin: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#efefef">
<table class="body-wrap" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; width: 100% !important; height: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background: #efefef; margin: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#efefef"><tr style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td class="container" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; display: block !important; clear: both !important; max-width: 580px !important; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;"><!-- Message start -->

      <table style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; width: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td align="center" class="masthead" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; color: white; background: #71bc37; margin: 0; padding: 80px 0;" bgcolor="#71bc37"><h1 style="font-size: 32px; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.25; max-width: 90%; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">Something Big...</h1></td>
        </tr><tr style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td class="content" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; background: white; margin: 0; padding: 30px 35px;" bgcolor="white"><h2 style="font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.25; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 0;">Hi Stranger,</h2>
            <p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 0;">Kielbasa venison ball tip shankle. Boudin prosciutto landjaeger, pancetta jowl turkey tri-tip porchetta beef pork loin drumstick. Frankfurter short ribs kevin pig ribeye drumstick bacon kielbasa. Pork loin brisket biltong, pork belly filet mignon ribeye pig ground round porchetta turducken turkey. Pork belly beef ribs sausage ham hock, ham doner frankfurter pork chop tail meatball beef pig meatloaf short ribs shoulder. Filet mignon ham hock kielbasa beef ribs shank. Venison swine beef ribs sausage pastrami shoulder.</p>
            <table style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; width: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td align="center" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 0;"> <a href="#" class="button" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; color: white; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 4px; background: #71bc37; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-color: #71bc37; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 20px 8px;">Share the Awesomeness</a> </p></td>
              </tr></table><p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 0;">By the way, if you're wondering where you can find more of this fine meaty filler, visit <a href="http://baconipsum.com" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; color: #71bc37; text-decoration: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Bacon Ipsum</a>.</p>
            <p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 0;"><em style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; margin: 0; padding: 0;">– Mr. Pen</em></p></td>
        </tr></table></td>
  </tr><tr style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td class="container" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; display: block !important; clear: both !important; max-width: 580px !important; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;"><!-- Message start -->

      <table style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; width: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td class="content footer" align="center" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; background: white none; margin: 0; padding: 30px 35px;" bgcolor="white"><p style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; font-weight: normal; color: #888; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="center">Sent by <a href="#" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; color: #888; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Company Name</a>, 1234 Yellow Brick Road, OZ, 99999</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; font-weight: normal; color: #888; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="center"><a href="mailto:" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; color: #888; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 0;">hello@company.com</a> | <a href="#" style="font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; color: #888; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Unsubscribe</a></p></td>
        </tr></table></td>
  </tr></table></body>
</html>
```

I recommend if they make many changes Emogrifier not save the template, to make them easier to apply changes and then make the process **Emogrifier**.

I hope you find it useful.

*Thank you very much!*